# 'this' not referring to correct method

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that the 'this' selector doesn't refer to the correct element. I searched on jquery and it says that you have to type: "$(this)" to refer to the first function, but this doesn't work.

Html:

```
<tbody id="tableBody">
            <tr>
                <td>Product 1</td>
                <td class="basisprijs">10.00</td>
                <td class="aantal"><input type="text" name="txtAtl1" value="0" id="txt1"/></td>
                <td class="btw">6</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product 2</td>
                <td class="basisprijs">15.00</td>
                <td class="aantal"><input type="text" name="txtAtl2" value="0" id="txt2"/></td>
                <td class="btw">21</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product 3</td>
                <td class="basisprijs">12.20</td>
                <td class="aantal"><input type="text" name="txtAtl3" value="0" id="txt3"/></td>
                <td class="btw">21</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product 4</td>
                <td class="basisprijs">13.00</td>
                <td class="aantal"><input type="text" name="txtAtl4" value="0" id="txt4"/></td>
                <td class="btw">21</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(setup);

function setup()
{
$('input').keyup(function refresh(){
    $("#tableBody tr").each(function() {
        $('this td:last-child').html("test");       
    });
});
}
```

Comment: `'this'` within a string and `this` the variable are two *very* different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$('input').keyup(function refresh(){
    $("#tableBody tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find('td:last-child').html("test");       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td:last-child',this).html("test");
```

The other way is

```
$(this).find("td:last-child");
```

Comment: this is not jQ object here.

Comment: you don't need to wrap `this` in your first snippet

Comment: A jQuery object is not required for the context argument in the first option above.  It can be either a DOM object or a jQuery object.  Mohammad, you should put that first option back the way you had it.  Royi's comment does not matter.